# \r\n returns while storing values in XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am tring to make a simple XML from a string. It works perfectly fine, but \r\n gets added in between.

What change should I do ?

```
   String doubleQuote = @"";
     String backSlash = @"\";

    XElement xmlInReturn = new XElement("toast",
        new XAttribute("activationType", backSlash + doubleQuote + "abc" + backSlash + doubleQuote),                
        new XElement("def",
         new XElement("ghi",
            new XAttribute("jkl", "mno"),
            new XElement("pqr", headerText),
            new XElement("stu", BodyContents)
              )));
```

Here, \r\n gets added when I retrieve xmlInReturn.

Comment: You should not do anything as new lines are insignificant in XML.

Comment: Do you have to store the backSlash and doubleQuote? Why not put it on the business logic side of things?

Comment: Can you show add the 'retrieve' code to to the problem please, so that we know what you are using?